# How to know the selected datatable rows before form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following Datatable: [LIVE DATATABLES](http://live.datatables.net/vepedopa/38/)

Before I click a button to submit the form, I would like to know the ids of the selected rows.

What I've tried:

```
$( "#testrow" ).click(function() {
  console.log(DT4.rows().ids());
});
```

I used `rows().ids()` method ([official datatables api documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().ids()))
and I expected to get an array or something similar with the index numbers of the selected rows, but instead I am getting this:

[image: log result]

This method does not read the DOM id for the tr so I am wondering which is the best way to know which row was selected (from the DOM) before submitting a form.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();

        $('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        } );

        $('#button').click( function () {
            let data = table.rows('.selected').data()
            console.log(data)
        } );
    });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
            integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk=" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    
<button id="button">Get Row Selected</button>
<table id="example" class="display table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2008/10/16</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Michael Silva</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```